# reference a cell from another worksheet using a variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, reference

I'm trying to refer to another worksheet (BASE tab) in the same workbook. I run the code below inside a couple of loops where x and y increment based on certain conditions. I've messed around with the code but I haven't had any luck. This is what I have so far but it does not work.

```
Cells(i, j) = "='BASE tab'!R[" & x & "]C[ & y & ]"
```

I want cells(i,j) to reference the other cells so I don't have to run my lengthy macro for minor value changes.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956046/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Cells(i, j) = "='BASE tab'!R[" & x & "]C[" & y & "]"
```

Comment: This sort of issue could probably be identified easily if you are using the VBA editor to color `Identifier Text` different than the default color.  `Tools->Options->Editor Format->Identifier Text in the Code Colors`  It is very obvious here on SO where syntax highlighting is decent.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I spent hours on such dumb mistake.

Comment: ++ Nice! You posted an answer and not a comment! :P